# Member initialization lists with default arguments

Tags: c++, default-arguments, member-initialization

Is it possible use default arguments with member initialization lists?

```
Vector3::Vector3(double xI, double yI, double zI)
: x(xI=0), y(yI=0), z(zI=0)
{
}
```

The constructor always sets x, y, and z to 0 even if you call it with setting the arguments.

Comment: Why not just `Vector3::Vector3(double xI=0, double yI=0, double zI=0) ...`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Vector3(double xI=0, double yI=0, double zI=0);  

Vector3::Vector3(double xI, double yI, double zI)
    : x(xI), y(yI), z(zI)
    {
    }
```

Also, if you are wondering what your code is doing, it's simply setting your parameters to be 0, then passing the value of them (now 0) to initialize the members.

Comment: Doesn't work. `error: no matching function for call to Vector3::Vector3(double, double)`

Comment: is your constructor accessible? (eg public?)

Comment: @matt Ah. I found it. You need to remove the `=0` parts from the implementation and only have it on the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator `=` always return what it has assigned to left side variable, in your case it return `0`, which get assigned to `x`,`y` and `z`.